# Adding tags to libtiff

Tags: tags, libtiff

libtiff gives us warning with some tags "unknown field with tag...... encountered". To solve this we have found through google way through adding tag definitions for the tags reported as unknown (http://libtiff.maptools.org/addingtags.html). It says include the tag in tiff.h and tif_dirinfo.c. We did that and the libtiff still report this warning. I have found out that three of the reported tags already were in tif.h and tif_dirinfo.c even before we started to change it. And still the libtiff report them. 
They are mostly exif tags. I tried to insert to tif image by exiftool another exif tag, which is defined in tif.h and tif_dirinfo.c, just to check if the libtiff  works well with other defined tags and this tag was o.k. with libtiff, without warning.

Could you please share if you have ever met this problem and how have you solved it? Or any suggestions?

The reported tags are 34858, 36867, 36868,37393, 37510, 40091,40092,40093,40094,40095,40961,65001.
Tags 368687,36868, 37510 and 40961 already have definitions there, but libtiff keeps reporting them as unknown.

Thank you